# Origin of the rimshot

Tags: history

This might be a bit too obscure, but you never know what other people know, so...

Anyone know the origin of the rimshot, as used to emphasize a joke?  You know, like the representation here:

[image]

Comment: To me, the oddest thing is that it's called a rimshot, yet doesn't necessarily contain one. Case in point - http://instantrimshot.com

Answer (score 1):

The origin of the rimshot is an aural cue to let an audience know when a joke has ended and it's time to laugh. This was commonly used in Vaudeville (predecessor of modern day cabaret and stand-up comedy) where they used comedians to keep the audience entertained. It's unclear whether or not it was specifically created for Vaudeville.